# How to save an image in .gif format?

Tags: php, image, store

I use [ImageManipulator](https://gist.github.com/marplemr/9178810) library to store images. It supports `.gif` format as well:

```
.
.

    switch ($type) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF  :
            $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG :
            $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG  :
            $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            break;
        default             :
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Image type $type not supported");
    }

.
.
```

The issue is I cannot save a moving image (I mean .gif format, something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xhYB.gif)). It will be a saved as a non-moving image (I guess the first frame of that .gif) image. Something like [this](https://lamtakam.com/img/uploaded_images/1/1539435854.gif). Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: the GD library does not support animated gifs, you will need to use another library

Comment: This blog post is probably interesting https://www.jeroenvanwissen.nl/weblog/php/howto-generate-animated-gif-with-php He shows a working example. The GIFEncoder class he uses come from www.phpclasses.org - an incredibly gaudy looking site...